# About powershell variable scope

Tags: powershell

powersell variable scope include:global,script,private,local.

I test a variable in loop, bug why it have value outside loop?

```powershell
$a=$false
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 10; $i++) {
    $private:recObj=@{}
    $private:recObj.id=$i
    if ($i -lt 6) {
        $a=$true
    }else {
        $a=$false
    }

    $private:recObj.a=$a
    $private:recObj.b="2323"
}

$private:recObj #recObj is private, why here have output? I want it is null
```

the result:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
b                              2323
id                             9
a                              False
```

Answer (score 4):

Loop bodies in PowerShell are not scopes.  Private in this case is the entire script.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in this, but I want to highlight few things.

Scopes are like our Dot Net Scopes:

- *Global* is public,
- *Script* is internal,
- *Private* is private,
- *Local* is current stack level

Next one is the **Visiblity**

By default powershell visiblity is Public.

if you use

```
(Get-Variable -Name recObj).Visibility
```

you should see the visibility of that variable.
If you consider the for loops as a separate scope, then its wrong in PS.

Third, you do not need to declare everywhere private; one time will do that:

```
$a=$false
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 10; $i++) {
    $private:recObj=@{}
    $recObj.id=$i
    if ($i -lt 6) {
        $a=$true
    }else {
        $a=$false
    }

    $recObj.a=$a
    $recObj.b="2323"
}
$recObj
```

But you want to restrict it , then you explicitly make the visibility private.

```
 Set-Variable recObj -Visibility Private
```

Hope it helps you in better understanding.